# Check_mk on auto-scaling non-public servers

Tags: nagios, autoscaling, check-mk

In the company I work on, currently all monitoring is "mandated" to happen using check_mk.

This forces some of our deployments in AWS to always have public IPs on all machines, and then someone has to go install the agent and open the ports.

Ideally, some other method of communication would exist without NAT the need for, port forwarding, etc.

Is it possible to still use check_mk, but having check_mk to push data into Nagios instead of having a port opened? What other options exists in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty answer: have a cron on the ec2 instances which runs the check_mk_agent script and uploads the result as a file to your check_mk server, then use a [custom datasource](https://mathias-kettner.com/cms_datasource_programs.html) (which will probably boil down to "cat") to read the file